# Are Picard’s badge pops genuine behind-the-scenes bloopers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I just encountered a funny video on X:
https://x.com/tercio_miranda/status/1740941520684175522

The video shows Picard’s badge popping, and is so realistic with sound effects that it doesn’t look fan-made.

Was it a behind-the-scenes blooper from a DVD? What’s the original source of this video?

Comment: Realistic? Really?

Comment: So realistic! And it really feels like whoever posted it is attractive and talented and smells nice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Seems fake.

Seems like someone taking advantage of the [Picard Maneuver](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Picard_Maneuver) (Patrick Stewart tugging his uniform shirt down; see the appendices in link.) for a joke.

This a very apparent when in group situations where he is at a conference table and somehow “pops” the combadge across the table in front of others.

[image]

Really? And nobody noticed or even reacted?

> “…so realistic with sound effects…”

Really? What sound effect would a piece of metal and plastic make when it “pops” off of fabric? To me, the popping sound is the fakest thing about the video!

I say this is a fake. A very good (and creative) fake, but still a fake.

PS: If this were a real thing, I think the incredibly astute world of *Star Trek* fandom would have picked up on this and integrate the phenomenon as part of their cosplay.

PPS: This video seems to have originated from the Facebook account of someone known as
“[Spock Pointy-ears Vulcan](https://facebook.com/watch/Spock-Pointy-ears-Vulcan-147055725357224)” who seems to have posted dozens of modified *Star Trek* related videos to their account. Specifically, [this one](https://facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=pfbid02XyTYWAaSdWw81XDjMQ7tfVjUKCdD6G4TgfF44DjFRjgoVn9EACe3tkFpaR9WFKJel&id=147055725357224) as well as [this one](https://facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=pfbid02qxdfcpAaaRucTzbEeEfKKDFur7Yud1FRXvhuzREUazUv4Uvsx1c71ZvPPGo6yMgul&id=147055725357224) seem to be the source of the video you found on X.

Comment: Indeed, the fact that these have music overtop would confirm that. https://geektyrant.com/news/funny-star-trek-the-next-generation-fan-videos-features-captain-picards-badge-popping-off-whenever-he-tugs-his-shirt